# Using GoDaddy's SMTP server emails not connecting

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, server-side, godaddy-api

I am trying to send emails using `PHPMailer` using GoDaddy's `SMTP` servers (since I hear they blocked Gmail's SMTP or else I would be using that). Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";


$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];

$message = "Name:  ".$name."\r\n".
"Email:  ".$email_from."\r\n".
"Telephone:  ".$telephone."\r\n";
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "localhost";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->Port = 50;


    $mail->From = $email_from;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addAddress($email_to);

    $mail->addReplyTo($email_from);
    $mail->Subject = "Info";
    $mail->Body = $message;


    if ($_POST["submit"]){
        if(!$mail->send()){
            echo "Mailer error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else{
            echo "Message sent successfully";
        }

    }

}
```

I have looked up so many solutions but I couldn't find anything that helps. Basically non of the GoDaddy `SMTP` configurations I've tried worked. I get the error: `Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`.

How should I configure this so it works? Thanks.

Comment: reads like it is actually sending so its probaly being marked as spam and not seen, have you tried sending to different addresses?

Comment: @tim nvm it actually doesn't work, doesn't connect at all. :(

Comment: then add `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` and see what the actual problem is

Comment: @tim here's the thing, I talked to GoDaddy and they sent me a test file that uses the same SMTP configurations

Comment: your statements are contradictory. its impossible to help.

Comment: @tim Their test file uses the same SMTP configurations but when I use them they don't work. You can think the code is the issue, but if I used the Gmail SMTP service on XAMPP it works perfectly. What could be the issue?